# Applying time series forecasting model in categorised data

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

My dataset looks like this

```
+-------+--------+----------+
|     ID|     Val|      Date|
+-------+--------+----------+
|Ax3838J|81119.73|2021-07-01|
|Ax3838J|81289.62|2021-07-02|
|Ax3838J|81385.62|2021-07-03|
|Ax3838J|81385.62|2021-07-04|
|Ax3838J|81385.62|2021-07-05|
|Bz3838J|81249.76|2021-07-02|
|Bz3838J|81324.28|2021-07-03|
|Bz3838J|81329.28|2021-07-04|
|Bz3838J|81329.28|2021-07-05|
|Bz3838J|81329.28|2021-07-06|
+-------+--------+----------+
```

In real, there are 2.7 million `ID`s and total 56 million rows.
I am using Azure Databricks (PySpark) and trying to apply `fbprophet` on a sampled dataset of 10000 rows and it's already taking 5+ hours.

I am considering applying `NeuralProphet` and `StatsForecast` but not sure how can I apply the forecast model for each individual `ID` to do the forecasting on `ID` basis.

Any suggestions?

NB: while applying `fbprophet`, `val` becomes 'y' and `Date` becomes `ds` in the respective order.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
def forecast_balance(history_pd: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:

    anonym_cis = history_pd.at[0,'ID']
    
    # instantiate the model, configure the parameters
    model = Prophet(
        interval_width=0.95,
        growth='linear',
        daily_seasonality=True,
        weekly_seasonality=True,
        yearly_seasonality=False,
        seasonality_mode='multiplicative'
    )

    # fit the model
    model.fit(history_pd)

    # configure predictions
    future_pd = model.make_future_dataframe(
        periods=30,
        freq='d',
        include_history=False
    )

    # make predictions
    results_pd = model.predict(future_pd)
    results_pd.loc[:, 'ID'] = anonym_cis

    # . . .


    # return predictions
    return results_pd[['ds', 'ID', 'yhat', 'yhat_upper', 'yhat_lower']]

result_schema =StructType([
  StructField('ds',DateType()),
  StructField('CIS_ANONYM',IntegerType()),
  StructField('yhat',FloatType()),
  StructField('yhat_upper',FloatType()),
  StructField('yhat_lower',FloatType())
  ])

historic_data = df.filter(F.col('ds') < '2022-02-20')
 
group_results = (
    historic_data
    .groupBy('ID')
    .applyInPandas(forecast_balance, schema=result_schema)
    )
```

Comment: What "ID" is? If it is something like user ID, using it as a feature would mean that you cannot make predictions for any new user not available in the training dataset...

Comment: `ID` are fixed. I am trying to forecast `val` for each `ID` and that's where facing the problem.

Comment: Simple solution would be to have a separate time-series model per each ID, why this would not work for you?

Comment: Can you please suggest how? Especially how to I scale the model for each ID? [note: I have added the code that I used]

Comment: Create a separate dataset per each ID and train a standard time-series model for it. Would this be a bad idea?

Comment: for 2.7 million unique ID?

Comment: Why not? I don't know what your data it, so cannot tell.

Comment: can you share any reference doc or article to understand a bit more clearly how can I do so?

Comment: Maybe tell us more what your data is? What are the IDs? Why are they important? Is there any variability between IDs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`StatsForecast`](https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast) to perform your task. The library parallelizes the training for each time series (`ID`). `StatsForecast` receives a pandas dataframe with tree columns: `unique_id`, `ds`, `y`. So you have to rename your columns:

```
from statsforecast.core import StatsForecast
from statsforecast.models import auto_arima

df = df.rename(columns={'ID': 'unique_id', 'Val': 'y', 'Date': 'ds'})
df = df.set_index('unique_id')

fcst = StatsForecast(df, models=[auto_arima], freq='D')
forecasts = fcst.forecast(h=30)
```

You can use `StatsForecast` with `spark` trough [`fugue`](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue). [Here's](https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast/blob/main/experiments/fugue/nixtla.ipynb) and example.

If you use [`Ray`](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), you can also [scale your task](https://www.anyscale.com/blog/how-nixtla-uses-ray-to-accurately-predict-more-than-a-million-time-series).

Regarding using `prophet`, I recommend using other models such as the `AutoARIMA` from `StatsForecast`. With [this experiment](https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast/tree/main/experiments/arima_prophet_adapter) we have seen that it is a lot faster and more accurate than `prophet`.